# Subtract 2 case statements

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to subtract the 2 case statements like this:

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN fct.measure IN ('A')   
        THEN fct.month_value 
        ELSE NULL 
END
    - CASE 
          WHEN fct.measure IN ('B') 
              THEN fct.month_value 
              ELSE NULL 
      END AS discounts
```

This query doesn't throw a syntax error, but it returns all NULL.

The `month_value` corresponding to A is 3173.100000 and the month value corresponding to B is 8043.000000.

Any suggestions on how this could return the correct result instead of all NULL?

Comment: Please show how your data looks and what the entire query you tried looks like

Comment: That expression can *only* ever give `NULL` because one of your `CASE` expressions will **always** resolve the `NULL`. In your first you have `fct.measure in ( 'A')` for your `WHEN`, but in the latter `fct.measure in ( 'B')`. *If* `fct.measure` equals `'A'` (not sure why you are using `IN`) it **cannot** equal `'B'`, so it is *impossible* for both expressions to resolve to TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you need some kind of conditional aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    MAX(CASE WHEN measure = 'A' THEN month_value END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN measure = 'B' THEN month_value END);
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col;
```

This assumes that your table structure looks something like the following:

```
col | measure | month_value
1   | A       | 3173.10
1   | B       | 8043.00
```

We aggregate by each `col` value, and then use conditional aggregation to isolate the various month values based on the value of the `measure` column.

Comment: Iam trying:CASE WHEN fct.measure = 'A' THEN fct.month_value  end
   - CASE WHEN fct.measure = 'B' THEN fct.month_value  end . this too gives all null . Also putting a max logic will complicate the query as there are many columns that is having a logic . can it be done without any aggregate.

Comment: With below changes iam getting expected results CASE WHEN fct.measure = 'A' THEN fct.month_value ELSE 0 end
   - CASE WHEN fct.measure = 'B' THEN fct.month_value ELSE 0 end
   as discounts

Comment: @NehaNayal If green checkmark to the left is possible, it would be great.